# C# double for comprehension?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to do a double `for` comprehension in C#? For example, the following works:

```
var a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var b = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length).Select(i => a[i]).ToArray();
```

But when I try and adapt this code for the two-dimensional case, things don't work. Below I'm trying to iterate over the pixels of a bitmap:

`Color[] p = Enumerable.Range(0, Source.Width).Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, Source.Height).Select(j => Source.GetPixel(i, j))).ToArray()`.

Is there any way to get what I want? The error I'm currently getting is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[] to
>   System.Drawing.Color[]

Comment: *why* doesn't it work?  What problem is there with the code?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Drawing.Color>[] to System.Drawing.Color[].

Comment: `Color[]` is one dimensional

Comment: @thumbmunkeys: Is there a way to get a one dimensional array from my query?

Comment: yes you are getting an array of `IEnumerable<Color>`

Comment: Slightly tangential to your question, but if this is a Bitmap you're dealing with, you may want to look into [using LockBits/BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as the GetPixel method is pretty slow.  The data is also already essentially flat in this case, as well (though you have to be wary of Stride not matching Width in some cases.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer `Select` needs to be a `SelectMany` to flatten the projection:

```
Color[] p = Enumerable.Range(0, Source.Width)
                      .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(0, Source.Height)
                                                 .Select(j => Source.GetPixel(i, j)))
                      .ToArray();
```

or to create a jagged 2-D array add an inner `ToArray()`:

```
Color[][] p = Enumerable.Range(0, Source.Width)
                        .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, Source.Height)
                                               .Select(j => Source.GetPixel(i, j))
                                               .ToArray())
                        .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the way to do it if you really want to use `Enumerable.Range`, but, IMO, this is one of those cases that would be a lot cleaner if written as a traditional nested for loop.

Comment: @DanBryant: I agree -- you're probably right...I just was confused why the extension to a 2D array wasn't working. Thank you.